# Stop build looking for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll 4.2.0.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

We have a Xamarin Forms Project that builds fine in VS20198 but the iOS build fails on the hosted mac in Azure DevOps (ADO)

Looking at this output from ADO build

```
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5851930Z MTOUCH : error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'ProjectBreatheApp.iOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [/Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/ProjectBreatheApp/ProjectBreatheApp.iOS/ProjectBreatheApp.iOS.csproj]
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5852990Z   --- inner exception
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5899390Z   Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'ProjectBreatheApp.iOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'ProjectBreatheApp.Forms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'FreshMvvm, Version=1.0.7010.22624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5901640Z     at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00105] in <c00644197a08419abff2c4cf790b9f65>:0 
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5903940Z     at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/AssemblyResolver.cs:80 
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5904560Z     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.IMetadataScope scope) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:210 
2019-10-15T17:04:27.5906030Z      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I can see it is failing to find 4.2.0.0 version of STTE. That version does not exist and I don't believe it ever did. How can I tell the build to take a different version?

We are not directly referencing STTE, the library we are using, FreshMVVM that is in the linking stack trace is not referencing it directly and more importantly I do have a working ADO iOS build of a simple XF project that does use that FreshMVVM.

Plenty of other people have had issues with a reference to 4.2.0.0 STTE, they have suggested an explicit reference to the file. I could not get that to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue with System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions where my project builded fine locally but not in Azure Pipelines.

The issue is that the agent "macOS-10.14" does not uses by default the latest Mono and Xamarin.iOS SDK.

By switching to the latest XCode (11.1), NetCore 2.x, Mono (6.4) and Xamarin.iOS SDK solved the issue in my case.

Here are the Tasks that I've used to configure my pipeline:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 2.x'
  inputs:
    version: 2.x

- bash: |
   SYMLINK=6_4_0
       MONOPREFIX=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/$SYMLINK
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH"
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PKG_CONFIG_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig:$MONOPREFIX/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/bin:$PATH"

  displayName: 'Select Mono Version'

- bash: |
   echo "Select Xamarin Version"
       /bin/bash -c "sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_4_0"
  displayName: 'Select Xamarin Version'

- bash: |
   echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MD_APPLE_SDK_ROOT;]'/Applications/Xcode_11.1.app;sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_11.1.app/Contents/Developer

  displayName: 'Select XCode Version'
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

Just for reference here you can find what is installed in each image available in Azure Pipelines and how to select tools according to MS docs

[Azure Pipelines Image Generation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation)

[How can I manually select versions of tools on the Hosted macOS agent?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#xamarin)

Comment: I've spent a couple of days at least looking at this. Your solution works excellently although these kind of things feel like a hack but perhaps I am being naive. Thanks for your help #hero

Comment: I'm glad this solved your issue. The main thing is that, at least in my case I've updated VS to the latest version and I was expecting that by default Azure Pipelines uses the latest versions when released. Now I know that is not that way :D